# ngTemplateOutlet : templateRef.createdEmbeddedView is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I am trying to create a modular table.

To do that, I use template references and ng containers.

I have made this stackblitz, which is pretty simple :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xhely

When ran, it says the error

> TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

And I have looked online for a while now, and can't seem to find a solution to my issue.

Here is the related code.

### Directive

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[template]' })
export class TemplateDirective {
  @Input() template: string;
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

### Root component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<app-table [data]="data">
  <ng-template template="body" let-item>
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.nom}}</td>
  </ng-template>
</app-table>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [{ id: 1, nom: 'Max' }];
}
```

### Table component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateDirective } from './template.directive';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>NOM</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="template">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { $implicit: item }">
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @ContentChildren(TemplateDirective) templates: QueryList<any>;
  template: TemplateDirective;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.template = this.templates.first.template;
  }
}
```

### Edit

I have tried putting the template outside of the table selector and give it as in input to the table, and it seems to work. Would it be that you can't use content children to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you update your TableComponent to this, it works. Hope this solves your problem.

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>NOM</td>
 </thead>
 <tbody *ngIf="template">
    <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data"
                    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
                    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }">
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<ng-template #template let-item>
<td>{{item?.id}}</td>
<td>{{item?.nom}}</td>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it would be useful to explain solution in addition to providing the code